# Mesh Current Method.(Current assignment)

Tags: voltage, current-measurement, circuit-analysis

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fcXtif.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

I am trying to solve this using the mesh current method. I assigned the current direction as follows [image]

From this I used KVL for each loop and had the following:

loop (a):
$$1000(I_b-I_a)+5000I_a-12=0$$
loop (b):
$$-1000I_b+3-1000(I_b-I_a)=0$$

so from this I obtained:

$$I_b= \frac{1}{375} A
$$
and,
$$ I_a=\frac{7}{3000}A$$

which I know is incorrect since it is inconsistent with the circuit simulation.

Could someone point out where the error is? Is this a case where mesh current method doesn't work!?

Comment: Check for consistence, especially the direction of your current arrows versus the signs you use.

Comment: I made sure that the polarity of each resistor is assigned so that the current goes through the positive side.  However, I still don't see where the mistake is?

Comment: Check your signs in the first equation.

Comment: You defined \$I_2 = I_a\$ whereas it should be \$I_2 = -I_a\$.

Comment: e.g. in Ia & R2 you get +5000Ia but in Ib & R4 you have -1000Ib. That is inconsistent. Oh and I really like your *Is this a case where mesh current method doesn't work!?*.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your problem = errors due non-systematic assignments. You have wrong signs.

My suggestions

- when possible, use the wanted currents as loop current variables
- draw arrows for all  voltages in a loop, draw them from + to - assuming the loop currents positive
- start collecting the voltage terms from an easy to remember point and along the current direction (in the example the starting point is + terminal of a voltage source)

An example:

[image]